# pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch during gitlab CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab-ci, pg, pg-dump

Here is the error I get when the gitlab runner run my CI script:

```
pg_dump: server version: 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1); pg_dump version: 11.11 (Debian 11.11-0+deb10u1)
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
rails aborted!
failed to execute:
pg_dump -s -x -O -f /builds/steady-install-inc/steady-install-backend/db/structure.sql test
```

And here is the .gitlab-ci.yml file running rspec:

```
image: ruby:2.6.3

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

cache:
  key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  paths:
    - vendor/bundle

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install --deployment --without development -j $(nproc)

rspec:
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:13.2
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: test
    POSTGRES_USER: test
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
    DATABASE_URL: "postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@postgres/$POSTGRES_DB"
    DATABASE_CLEANER_ALLOW_REMOTE_DATABASE_URL: 'true'
  script:
    # Use example environment variables
    - cp config/application.yml.example config/application.yml
    - apt-get update -qy && apt-get install -y nodejs
    - apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-client libpq-dev
    - bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rspec
  coverage: '/\(\d+.\d+\%\) covered/'
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Can any see what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried around 5-10 suggestions online but most seemed to either be for unbuntu or docker which I'm not fully sure how to implement or they just didn't work.

Anything helps!

Edit:
I also forgot to mention I recently switched to a schema.rb format to a structure.sql format but I'. not sure if that is part of the problem as my specs pass when I run them locally.

Answer (score 1):

I lack expertise with `gitlab-ci.yml`, but I wanted to mention Gitlab's CI Linter- have you tried that? It's kinda hidden. On the left menu choose CI/CD > Pipelines and it will be in the far right corner of the pipeline view.

[Gitlab pipeline view with CI lint button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukmzx.png)

Comment: I've never noticed that - but the syntax in the file is all good, just when it runs it fails because the dump doesn't work :/ ty though!